# topological dimension of inverse limit of compact spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact metric space with topological dimension ${\rm dim}(X)>0$. Let $f: X\times X\to X$ be a continuous and surjective map. Define a family of maps $f_n: X^{n+1}\to X^{n}$ for $n\ge 1$ by $f_1=f$ and $f_{n+1}(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n+1})=(f_{n}(x_1, \dots, x_{n}), f(x_n, x_{n+1}))$. I think that the topological dimension of the inverse limit of the family $(X^n, f_n)$ is infinite. But I can not prove it. I will be appreciated if anyone could prove such statement or disprove by a counter-example.

Thanks in advance. Any comments are welcome!

Comment: You certainly want $\dim(X)>0$: if $\dim(X)=0$ then the projective limit has topological dimension $0$.

Comment: @YCor Yes, I changed this error. Thanks for pointing it out.